# what happens when a client reaches zero credits in smb2?

Tags: smb

I have a trace for a connection where the number of credit charged exceeds number of credits granted by the server. 
Also Is is possible for client to send any more requests after that, without server granting more credits??
I have some more read requests after that point where the credits for client have become zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MS-SMB2, the client should await the grant of new credits from the server before sending more requests. The CreditCharge field of the SMB2 header cannot be larger than the available credits in the sequence window. If more credits are needed than the client has available, the client should not send the request. A trick is to reduce the length of the requested read operation, so that you can fit it in the sequence window.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MS specifications for SMB2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-smb2/2e366edb-b006-47e7-aa94-ef6f71043ced), the server must ensure that a client can't reach zero credits, otherwise the client would no longer able to send more messages:

> The server MUST ensure that the number of credits held by the client
> is never reduced to zero. If the condition occurs, there is no way for
> the client to send subsequent requests for more credits.

Thus, if the client as no credit left, this is indicative of a server bug.